# How to sum values ​in nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have array

```
const array1 = [[5, 10, 15], [1, 2, 3]];
```

How can I get such a summed array from it?

```
const sum = [6, 12, 18];
```

Comment: How did you get 3 int as sum from 2x3 inputs?

Comment: @0stone0 The inner arrays seem to be summed by index (5 + 1 = 6 etc). @ Timo Will there only ever be more than two arrays inside your parent array? What if the arrays have inconsistent lengths?

Comment: Damn it's to early: `array1[0].map((n, i) => n + array1[1][i]);`

Comment: I've removed references and the tag relating to React, since this is really just a JS question. If there's some reason it needs a React context, please expand the question to explain why.

Comment: a parent table can have more than two tables. I use React. @Mandeep Kaur's code seems to only work for two tables?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have same format as you shown here.

```
const array1 = [[5, 10, 15], [1, 2, 3]];

const newArray = array1[0].map((i, index) => {
   return i + array1[1][index]
})

console.log(newArray, "newArray")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [[5, 10, 15], [1, 2, 3]];
result=[]
for(let i =0;i<array1.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<array1[i].length;j++){
    if(!result[j]){
      result[j]=array1[i][j];
    }else{
      result[j]+=array1[i][j];
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```